# Typescript Error: type 'string' can't be used to index type X

Tags: typescript

I have a simple code:

```
const allTypes = { jpg: true, gif: true, png: true, mp4: true };
const mediaType = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
return Boolean(allTypes[mediaType]);
```

TypeScript is complaining:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ jpg: boolean; gif: boolean; png: boolean; mp4: boolean; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ jpg: boolean; gif: boolean; png: boolean; mp4: boolean; }'.  TS7
```

I think I need to treat `mediaType` as `keyof typeof allTypes`, but don't know how.

For sake of completion, the complete code is:

```
// these are all the types of media we support
const allTypes = { jpg: true, gif: true, png: true, mp4: true };

const MediaGallery = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [ filters, setFilters ] = useState(allTypes);
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            {mediaList
                .filter(({ url }) => {
                    const type = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
                    return Boolean(filters[type]);
                })
                .map(({ url, caption, hash }) => <Media url={url} caption={caption} key={hash} />)}
            <FiltersPanel onFiltersChanged={(newFilters: any) => setFilters(newFilters)} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

All you need is to define the **index signature**:

```js
const allTypes: {[key: string]: boolean} = { jpg: true, gif: true, png: true, mp4: true };
```

## [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)

> Similarly to how we can use interfaces to describe function types, we can also describe types that we can “index into” like `a[10]`, or `ageMap["daniel"]`. Indexable types have an *index signature* that describes the types we can use to index into the object, along with the corresponding return types when indexing. Let’s take an example:
>
> ```
> interface StringArray {
>   [index: number]: string;
> }
>
> let myArray: StringArray;
> myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];
>
> let myStr: string = myArray[0];
> ```
>
> Above, we have a `StringArray` interface that has an index signature. This index signature states that when a `StringArray` is indexed with a `number`, it will return a `string`.

## [Utility type: `Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

Another solution is to use the TypeScript utility type [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type):

> Constructs an object type whose property keys are `Keys` and whose property values are `Type`. This utility can be used to map the properties of a type to another type.

```js
const allTypes: Record<string, boolean> = { jpg: true, gif: true, png: true, mp4: true };

for (const key of Object.keys(allTypes)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${allTypes[key]}`);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at the answer from LCC below. The problem with Record<> and unconstrained Index Signatures is that you are widening the type to all possible records. So if I asked for "allTypes["not-a-picture"]", TSC would assume the resulting value would be a boolean, even though it would be "undefined". And if you did a check against "undefined", ESLint would tell you that it was an unnecessary check, even though it's necessary.

You're mapping Keys to Values. Why not use a Map<>?

Answer (score 28):

You can use indexable types, but this widens the type of `allTypes` to contain any (string) key, when it looks like you have a limited list of keys that you want to support.

A better solution - allowing you to use the proper type of `allTypes` - is (as you already indicated in your question) to tell the compiler your assumption that `mediaType` is one of the **keys of** the **type of** `allTypes` with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```js
return Boolean(allTypes[mediaType as keyof typeof allTypes]);
```

This type is in this case equivalent to the union type
`"jpg" | "gif" | "png" | "mp4"`, but it is computed automatically.

(How you ensure that your assumption is correct at runtime is a separate concern, of course.)

Comment: This make sense, as TS is explicitly suggesting the same `'string' can't be used to index type '{ jpg: boolean; gif: boolean; png: boolean; mp4: boolean; }'.`

Comment: This works for JSON objects as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) utility function which safely checks whether a given string is a property of an object:

```
function isKeyOf<O extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  object: O,
  key: string | number | symbol,
): key is keyof O {
  return key in object;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
return isKeyOf(allTypes, mediaType) ? allTypes[mediaType] : false
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// In this branch TypeScript knows that mediaType is a key of allTypes
```

Answer (score -1):

my solution:

```
{ // in tsconfig.json
  ...
  strict: true; // optional
}
```

---

```
let args = {};
Object.keys(args).forEach((key: string): void => {
  const value = (args as {[key: string]: any})[key];
});
```