# Need TypeScript annotation to access object property via a variable

Tags: typescript

In plain JavaScript, we can read the value of an object's property using a variable.

That is, this is valid:

```
let obj = { a: 100, b: 'Need help with TypeScript', c: new Date() };
let prop = 'b';
console.log( obj[prop] );  // Need help with TypeScript
```

However, the below TypeScript annotation declaring `prop` as a string results in the indicated index error.

```
let obj: object = { a: 100, b: 'Need help with TypeScript', c: new Date() };
let prop: string = 'b';
console.log( obj[prop] );  // TypeScript error element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
```

How should I be annotating the above?

**Edit Dec. 9, 2019:**  When I posted the question, I had assumed there would be a generic answer and not an answer explicitly dependent upon my example object.

My use case is a function, that accepts as an argument a property's name. The function sorts an array based on the name of the property passed. The original JavaScript code that I'm porting to TS will sort any array of objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Error: type 'string' can't be used to index type X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667198/typescript-error-type-string-cant-be-used-to-index-type-x)

Comment: Don't annotate `obj` at all; let it be inferred as type `{a: number, b: number, c: number}`.  As for `prop`, you also don't need to annotate it, but you should either change `let` to `const`, or use `let prop = "b" as const`, like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBRAlgFwBYQE5IG8BYAKCSQBsIMkB7AIwCskBeQpEALiQEYAGPgBok9bgCYBw+NwDMApAF8A3KXLxawKDRi5aMVkgDk9QyrJJ1m2lQB0FWgHMAFA0YBtHXoC6ASiXkAegCkCT5SBVJQSFgEZAB5fGJzKhpXAwIObn4hEXFJC1l5ZVVKaiRPfTZjQw4oCw0tMzUG6wg7RxcmD10YX38kIJCBcKA).

Comment: @jcalz - thank you for your comment and example. I looked at the example and it works, but I don't understand why it works. Why does declaring the property as a a `const` make a difference. I've not yet had a chance to try your suggestion for my specific case. I will though. (Please see my edits made today.)

Comment: "Why does declaring the property as a `const` make a difference" The compiler treats `const` as signaling the intent that the value will not change (this is only true for primitives, but whatever), so it infers it as a narrower type.  If you write `let prop = "b"`, it guesses that you want `prop` to be a `string` because you might change it to some other `string` later.  If you write `const prop = "b"`, it knows that `prop` will always be `"b"` so it infers the string literal type `"b"`.  I'd be happy to turn this into an answer if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid `object` as a type, TS cannot deduct from this what to do.

Consider adding a type, that allows what you want to do:

```
let obj: { [key: string]: number } = { a: 100, b: 200, c: 300 };
let prop: string = 'b';
console.log( obj[prop] );
```

You can even refine this more by using the `[key in type]` syntax, where type is a type definition:

```
type props = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
let obj: { [key in props]: number } = { a: 100, b: 200, c: 300 };
let prop: props = 'b';
console.log(obj[prop]);
```

Later the access to the named property could be simplified by using an interface. Using this as a basis, the `keyof` operator is very helpful:

```
interface IProps{
  a: number,
  b: number,
  c: number
}
let obj: { [key in keyof IProps]: number} = { a: 100, b: 200, c: 300 };
let prop: keyof IProps = 'b';
console.log(obj[prop]);
```

The last is more for demonstration, reference and showcase, not exactly the perfect answer the OP was looking for.

Comment: I guess accepting an answer late is better than never accepting it. :-) (I did not end up adopting TS.)