# How to deal with this error? 'Index signature is missing in type...'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to enrich this very nice tutorial from Josh Hicks

https://medium.com/@joshblf/dynamic-nested-reactive-forms-in-angular-654c1d4a769a

by adding some FormGroups and FormArrays, but in the form-model class

```
export class TeamForm {

  group1 = new FormGroup(new MyGroupForm(new MyGroup()));

  constructor(team: Team) {

    if (team.group1) {
      this.group1.setValue(team.group1);
    }
  }
}
```

this line

```
group1 = new FormGroup(new MyGroupForm(new MyGroup()));
```

returns the below error

```
Argument of type 'MyGroupForm' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
Index signature is missing in type 'MyGroupForm'.
```

Here is the `MyGroupForm` class

```
import { FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { MyGroup } from "./mygroup.model";

export class MyGroupForm {
  Input1 = new FormControl();
  Input2 = new FormControl();

  constructor(groupValue: MyGroup) {

    this.Input1.setValue(groupValue.Input1);
    this.Input1.setValidators([Validators.required]);

    this.Input2.setValue(groupValue.Input2);
  }
}
```

and this is the `MyGroup` class

```
export class MyGroup {
  Input1: string;
  Input2: string;

  constructor(value?) {
    if (value) {
      this.Input1 = value.Input1;
      this.Input2 = value.Input2;
    }
  }
}
```

The same code in stackblitz, returns the same error in the code editor, but builds fine!

Now, here is the weird thing!

If I replace the dot(.) in this filename
`mycontrol-form.model.ts`
 for a comma(,) like this: `mycontrol-form,model.ts`
the error disappears. But this only in stackblitz!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-nested-formarray-with-service

Apparently I'm doing something wrong, and I would much appreciate a little help with this issue...

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57667198/1164465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I learned how to implement index signatures in Classes. What I was missing is that I hadn't defined any type for the declared variables in the class. So, in my case the solution was as simple as this:

```
export class MyGroupForm  {

  Input1: FormControl = new FormControl();
  Input2: FormControl = new FormControl();
}
```

Now, if we want to define the general model for our objects we create a type interface and we implement it in our class like this:

```
interface IndexSignature {
  [key: string]: FormControl;
}

export class MyGroupForm implements IndexSignature {
  [key: string]: FormControl;

  Input1 = new FormControl();
  Input2 = new FormControl();
}
```

if our objects are of more than one type we can declare them like so:

```
interface IndexSignature {
  [key: string]: FormControl | FormArray;
}

export class MyGroupForm implements IndexSignature {
  [key: string]: FormControl | FormArray;

  Input1 = new FormControl();
  Array1 = new FormArray([]);
}
```

or in this specific case where both `FormControl` and `FormArray` are of type `AbstractControl` we just define this type:

```
interface IndexSignature {
  [key: string]: AbstractControl;
}

export class MyGroupForm implements IndexSignature {
  [key: string]: AbstractControl;

  Input1 = new FormControl();
  Array1 = new FormArray([]);
}
```

This is my understanding of index signatures. If anyone wants to add or correct anything, feel free to do so...