# Typescript - expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript

```js
// common.js

const boxNames = ['one', 'two'];

module.exports {
  boxNames,
}
```

```
const common = require("./common.js");
const boxNames = common.boxNames;
const messages = {
  'one': {
      id: 'some id',
      text: 'some text',
  },
  'two': {
    id: 'some id',
    text: 'some text',
  },
};
const disabled = boxNames.map((key: string) => messages[key]);
```

The above code produces the TypeScript error for the `messages[key]` statement:

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of
> type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ one: { id: string; text:
> string; }; two: { id: string; text: string; }; }'.   No index
> signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ one:
> { id: string; text: string; }; two: { id: string; text: string; }; }'.

I am declaring `key` as a string and the keys of `messages` are strings, so what's the problem?

(Worth noting here that `messages` is generated using the `defineMessages` method from the `react-intl` library.)

(I have seen a couple of answers on StackOverflow similar to this that refer to Object.keys, but am not sure how this relates to my TypeScript error.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The keys of the object `messages` are not of type `string`, they are of type `"one" | "two"`. In other words, they are string literals, which is a narrower type than simply `string` and cannot be indexed by the broader `string` type.

A simple way to get your example to compile is to turn the array of keys into a tuple:

```
const boxNames = ['one', 'two'] as const;
```

This effectively changes the type from `string[]` to `["one", "two"]`, and now when you map over them they will be of the correct type to index your object. As a side note, it is not necessary to explicitly set the type for `key` since this can be inferred from usage.

```
const disabled = boxNames.map((key) => messages[key]); // this is now fine
```

Another way you could type this is by assigning the keys of `messages` to the array:

```
const messages = {
  'one': {
      id: 'some id',
      text: 'some text',
  },
  'two': {
    id: 'some id',
    text: 'some text',
  },
};

const boxNames: (keyof typeof messages)[] = ['one', 'two'];

const disabled = boxNames.map((key) => messages[key]);
```

This is more dynamic than using tuples, and it will remain typesafe as you will not be allowed to include more strings in `boxNames` than exist as keys of `messages`. I *imagine* this would still work in the `require` scenario you are describing although I don't have an environment set up to test it right now.

I think the main takeaway here is that either `boxNames` needs to acquire a more specific type, or `messages` needs a less specific one. I'm assuming these keys *must* be an exact match, but perhaps your situation would actually be better suited by assigning `messages` a `string` indexed type instead - I think there's not enough context here to assume either way. That would mean dealing with the possbility in your code that you don't actually know if the array and object will match at run time.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Would prefer not to have to type the array as a tuple, given that 1) JavaScript does not support them (shouldn't TypeScript be limited to typing what is available in the native language), and 2) this goes against gradual adoption of TypeScript if I now have to convert the module that contains `boxNames` into a TypeScript file (in my case `boxNames` is an imported value from a file that is in CommonJS format as it need to be used in NodeJs too) (?)

Comment: See the edit. I believe this should help.

Comment: I was keen to use the `const boxNames: (keyof typeof messages)[] = ['one', 'two'];` example you gave, however, in my case, because messages and boxNames are both imported and boxNames in in a different repository, this might not work(?) I guess in this case I would need to define a type definition file in the boxNames repo(?)

Answer (score 2):

Typescript does not know that the elements of boxNames are keys of `messages`.

There is a clear distinction between `string` and `keyof`.

There are several ways you can tell TS that a string is a key of an object.

Without testing it myself, you may be able to do this:

```
boxNames.map((key: keyof typeof messages) => messages[key])
```

You want to look up how to use the `keyof` keyword, it is necessary to index objects in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an object like the below without giving type, the inferred type of the object would be `Record<'one' | 'two', string>`.

```
const numberCounter = {
 one: 'one',
 two: 'two'
}
```

So, what we have to remember here the keys of the object would always be a union of literal types, and the values of the object would be a union of the type of value.

Here in the below example, keys are a union of 'one' and 'two', and values are only string type (union of string and string is a string.)

I used to type the object like below, so I never come across such a problem. Here I explicitly saying that my object keys are of string type.

```
const boxNames = ['one', 'two'] ;

interface Type {
  id: string;
  text: string;
}
const messages: Record<string, Type> = {
  one: {
      id: 'some id',
      text: 'some text',
  },
  two: {
    id: 'some id',
    text: 'some text',
  },
};
// key is already inferred as string
const disabled = boxNames.map(key => messages[key]);
console.log(disabled);
```

If you don't want to explicitly say that the object keys are string, then @lawrence-witt [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953765/13847690) would be the best fit here.

There is one more way to make keys a union of "one" and "two".

```
const boxNames = ['one', 'two'];

const messages = {
  one: {
      id: 'some id',
      text: 'some text',
  },
  two: {
    id: 'some id',
    text: 'some text',
  },
};

type Key = keyof typeof messages;

// here we are doing type cast of string into union of `one` and `two`.
//boxNames key are of string type
const disabled = boxNames.map(key => messages[key as Key]);
console.log(disabled);
```

Comment: Does this suggest there is an issue with the type definition of the return of `defineMessages`?

Comment: Can't say much about this 

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution I found on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64136988/164439) looks like this:

```
const disabled = boxNames.map((key: string) => messages[key as keyof typeof messages]);
```

The key bit is: `messages[key as keyof typeof messages]`

As I understand it, this is using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (`as`) to ensure that the `key` string is one of (and *only* one of) the keys on the `messages` object, which in this case is the union type `"one" | "two"` created by the [keyof operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) (like the one manually created in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953765/164439)).

I think it might be the same as the [`key: keyof typeof messages`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) answer, also here, but inlined.