# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' for a React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to access a nested object structure using object keys, but TypeScript gives me the error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type...

My color themes object structure is as follows:

```js
colors: {
    background: string;
    text: string;
    black: string;
    white: string;
    yellow: {
        100: string;
        200: string;
        300: string;
        400: string;
        500: string;
        600: string;
        700: string;
        800: string;
        900: string;
    };
    green: {
        100: string;
        ... 7 more ...;
        900: string;
    };
    red: {
        ...;
    };
    cyan: {
        ...;
    };
    purple: {
        ...;
    };
    gray: {
        ...;
    };
}
```

But when I am accessing the color, it shows me the error. Please help. I am not able to access the themes.colors[color][weight]
Error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to define the `colors` object as a record type:

```js
colors: Record<string, any> = {
    background: string;
    text: string;
    black: string;
    ...
};
```

Or use a typecast on the index key:

```js
export const getColor = (color: string, weight: number, alpha = 1) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return hexToRgba(theme.colors[color as keyof typeof theme.colors][weight], alpha);
};
```

Another option, would be to use a typecast on the `colors` object:

```js
export const getColor = (color: string, weight: number, alpha = 1) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return hexToRgba((theme.colors as {[key: string]: any})[color][weight], alpha);
};
```

See Stack Overflow question [Typescript Error: type 'string' can't be used to index type X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57667198/1164465).

Comment: @DhruvKothari If you want precise type checking, then you could define a `ThemeColors` interface or a `ThemeColors` type. This would be especially appropriate if you use the theme colors in several places in your app. If, however, the theme colors are only used in one or two places, then using `any` is probably ok.

Comment: @DhruKothari If this answer solved your problem, could you mark it as the accepted answer?