# typescript how to type an object to iterate through some of its fields?

Tags: typescript, object, types

I am trying to convert a javascript code base into Typescript. I have this code in javascript:

```js
const keys = ["m1", "m2", "m3"]

const net = {}
net.p1 = undefined
net.p2 = undefined
net.m1 = function (str, num) {
}
net.m2 = function (str) {
}
net.m3 = function () {
}

net.p1 = 0
net.p2 = ""
const fs = []
for (let k of keys) {
    fs.push(net[k])
}
```

So I created an interface

```js
interface Net {
    p1: number | undefined
    p2: string | undefined
    m1: (str: string, num: number) => void
    m2: (str: string) => void
    m3: () => void
}
```

I made these changes

```js
...
const net = {} as Net
...
const fs = [] as object[]
...
```

the problem is that I get the following error

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGcoU.png)

I'm new to typescript and I really don't know how I should fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Error: type 'string' can't be used to index type X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667198/typescript-error-type-string-cant-be-used-to-index-type-x)

Comment: @yqlim I tried `[index: string]: object`, but now the fields p1 and p2 are failing.

Comment: [Typescript Error: type 'string' can't be used to index type X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667198/typescript-error-type-string-cant-be-used-to-index-type-x) does not solve my problem. I needed more specific typing.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[index: string]: object | number | string` so each type of every key you have can be indexed

Comment: How can I specify the type of the functions?