# Typescript: for .. in - define variable as keyof instead of string

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, types

When I iterate over keys in TypeScript the variable is being assigned the type of string instead of type keyof `object that I enumerate`.

Example:

```js
class Files {
  patches?: Data;
  website?: Data;
  github?: Data;
}

const files: Files = {};

for (const file in Files.prototype) {
  if (files[file]) {
    console.log(files[file])
  }
}
```

Error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Files'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Files'.

How can I solve this?

Comment: There are many Q&A on that error message. Please check. For instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64136988/5459839) to use `keyof` type assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the `file` outside of the `for in` with the correct type:

```
const files: Files = {};

let file: keyof typeof Files.prototype;

for (file in Files.prototype) {
  if (files[file]) {
    console.log(files[file]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Is there any other option, if I want to define file variable inside the for parameters?

Comment: If you want to go without the assertion then I don't think there is any other way to do it with `for in`